# c++ cstring merge and sort programming without using string library

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int strlength(char *str)
{
    int length = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (*(str + index)) {
        length++;
        index++;
    }
    return length;
}

char *mergeSortedStrings(char str1[], char str2[])
{   //get the length of the newstring
    int str1len = strlength(str1);
    int str2len = strlength(str2);
    int newStringlen = str1len + str2len;
    char *newString= new char[newStringlen];
    int i, j = 0;
    char temp;
    // copy str2 to the end of str1
    for (i = strlength(str1); i<256; i++)
    {
        str1[i] = str2[j];
        j++;
    }

    for (i=0; i<newStringlen;i++)
        for (j = newStringlen - 1; j > i; j--) {
            if (str1[j - 1] > str1[j])
            {
                temp = str1[j];
                str1[j] = str1[j - 1];
                str1[j - 1] = temp;

            }
        }
    str1[newStringlen] = '\0';
    return str1;
}


void main()
{
    char str1[20];
    char str2[20];

    cout << "Input string 1: ";
    cin >> str1;
    cout << "Input string 2: ";
    cin >> str2;

    cout << "The merged string is: " << mergeSortedStrings(str1, str2) << endl;
}
```

This is C++ string merge and sort programming without using string library functions. When I copied the contents of the final str1 to newString using for loop, it didn't give the correct result so that I just used str1 as the result. It gives out the correct result somehow but I think this may not be efficient. 
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: *This is C++ string merge and sort programming without using string library functions* -- Why this silly restriction?   Create your own simple string class and use that as if you were using `std::string`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Probably a class assignment. Such restrictions are common with homework in order to teach fundamentals.

Comment: OT: it’s `int main`

Comment: If that’s an assignment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher). Otherwise: don’t do it.

Comment: @CareyGregory -- This restriction goes overboard.  The OP isn't even allowed to use `strlen` or `strcat`.  What is gained by doing this?  All it does is encourage slower, buggy crap to be written by the students.

Comment: @CareyGregory char arrays are advanced, std::string is fundamental.

Comment: Hey, I'm not defending the assignment; I'm just guessing at the reason for the restriction.

Comment: First, stop mixing low level code with high level code.  Write yourself a string class.  Ppace concerns of the string class there.  You'll get itmwrong; write unit tests and exercise it to debug it.  Then use that string class in your sorting code.  If you try to write code like the above, 99/100 times even if you get it workimg it will have buffer off-by-one errors, and because that code is all over the place it'll be near impossible to track down.

Comment: `for (i = strlength(str1); i<256; i++)` what does this magic number 256 come from?

Comment: @kihyun-kim Your code works by sorting `str1` and does not do anything with `newString`. Show us the code that is not working to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you could do it using a custom String class. If you do not understand what's going on i suggest you to take a look at: [NULL terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). **Be careful, this is just an example to give you an idea on how you could approach the problem, there might be some errors.**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class String
{
    private:
        char *_str;
        int _len;

    public:
        String()
        {
            _str = NULL;
            _len = 0;
        }

        ~String()
        {
            if (_str != NULL)
                delete _str;
        }

        String(const char *str)
        {
            _str = NULL;
            _len = 0;

            if (str == NULL) return;

            int i;
            for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++);
            _len = i;

            _str = new char[_len];

            for (i = 0; i < _len; i++)
                _str[i] = str[i];
        }

        String(const String &s)
        {
            _str = NULL;
            _len = 0;

            if (s._len == 0) return;

            _str = new char[s._len];
            _len = s._len;

            for (int i = 0; i < _len; i++)
                _str[i] = s._str[i];
        }

        //constructor for concatenation
        String(const char* a, const char* b)
        {
            _str = NULL;
            _len = 0;

            if (a == NULL || b == NULL)
                return;

            int lenA;
            for (lenA = 0; a[lenA] != '\0'; lenA++);

            int lenB;
            for (lenB = 0; b[lenB] != '\0'; lenB++);

            _len = lenA + lenB;
            _str = new char[_len];

            for (int i = 0; i < lenA; i++)
                _str[i] = a[i];

            for (int i = 0; i < lenB; i++)
                _str[lenA + i] = b[i];
        }

        int getLength() const { return _len; }
        operator const char*() { return _str; }     

        void operator=(const char* str) 
        { 
            _str = NULL;
            _len = 0;

            if (str == NULL) return;

            int i;
            for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++);
            _len = i;

            if (_str != NULL)
                delete _str;

            _str = new char[_len];

            for (i = 0; i < _len; i++)
                _str[i] = str[i];
        }

        String operator+(const char* str)
        {
            return String(*this, str);
        }

        bool operator==(const char* str)
        {
            int len;
            for (len = 0; str[len] != '\0'; len++);

            if (len != _len) return false;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                if (str[i] != _str[i])
                    return false;

            return true;
        }

        bool operator<(const char* str)
        {
            int i;          
            for (i = 0; i < _len && str[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                if (_str[i] < str[i])
                    return true;
                else if (_str[i] > str[i])
                    return false;
            }

            return false;
        }

        bool operator<=(const char* str)
        {
            int i;          
            for (i = 0; i < _len && str[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                if (_str[i] < str[i])
                    return true;
                else if (_str[i] > str[i])
                    return false;
            }

            return (i == _len);
        }


        bool operator>(const char* str)
        {
            int i;          
            for (i = 0; i < _len && str[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                if (_str[i] > str[i])
                    return true;
                else if (_str[i] < str[i])
                    return false;
            }

            return (_len > i);
        }

        bool operator>=(const char* str)
        {
            int i;          
            for (i = 0; i < _len && str[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                if (_str[i] > str[i])
                    return true;
                else if (_str[i] < str[i])
                    return false;
            }

            return (_len >= i);
        }

        friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, String &s)
        {
            char str[512];
            is.getline(str, 512);

            s = str;

            return is;
        }
};

int main()
{

    String str1;
    String str2;


    cout << "Input string 1: ";
    cin >> str1;
    cout << "Input string 2: ";
    cin >> str2;

    String sortedMerged = str1 <= str2 ? str1 + str2 : str2 + str1;

    cout << sortedMerged;


    return 0;
}
```